# How can I select items in the array in echo statement in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP statement looks like this:

```
foreach ($books as $book) {
    if ($book['categoryId'] == $selectedCategory) {
       echo "<div class=\"flexItem\"> 
             <img src=\"images/books/$book['image']\"alt=\"Royal Easter\" class=\"image\">";
}
```

And I have a red line under `$book['image']`. I tried to fix it (solution recommended by PHPstorm) but I wanted to know the correct way of writing such an echo statement??

Comment: Very much opinion based, but I'd go with single quotes and concatenate the string, e.g. `echo '<div class="flexitem"><img src"images/books/"'.$book['image'].'" alt=....`. This way u don't need to escape that much

Comment: You can use sprintf `echo sprintf("<div class=\"flexItem\"><img src=\"images/books/%s\"alt=\"Royal Easter\" class=\"image\">",$book['image']);` or brackets `echo "<div class=\"flexItem\"><img src=\"images/books/{$book['image']}\"alt=\"Royal Easter\" class=\"image\">";`

Comment: There is no "right way" to interpolate variable string data into another string, there are multiple _methods_ that PHP's facilitates. In this case you need curly braces (`"...{$book['image']}..."`) because it's not a simple expression, but concatenation and tokenization (`sprintf()`) are also perfectly viable.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex because you're accessing a variable inside of double quotes to concatenate the string, it would be more clear to use curly braces around this var

Answer (score 2):

Your provided code has a missing closing bracket `}` & closing `</div>` tag, Give this a try:

```
foreach ($books as $book) {
   if ($book['categoryId'] == $selectedCategory) {
        echo '<div class="flexItem"> 
                <img src="images/books/'.$book['image'].'" alt="Royal Easter" class="image">
              </div>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Tip1**: When you are accessing array key inside string enclosed in `"`(double quotes) don't use `'` single quote in keys.

So `$book['image']` should be `$book[image]` only.

**Tip 2**: You can also use `{$book['image']}`, Use curly braces `{` to enclosed it.

Other alternative has already been mentioned by @Meta.